# Reference for a simple fact in measure theory (semi-algebras)

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory

What is the textbook where the following simple fact can be found:

A measure defined on a semi-algebra S can be extended to a sigma-algebra generated by S.

In the texbooks that I have looked into the theory of measures is done without semi-algebras (for examlple Halmos deals with measures using hereditary sigma-rings). However, it is convenient for my applications to use the above simple fact.

Comment: Check Royden's book.

Comment: Does this really need a reference?  For use in a paper, I'd consider it general knowledge, and just cite it as "Carathéodory's extension theorem".

Comment: @MichaelRenardy: Yes, it's in there: Section 17.5 in the fourth edition.

Comment: Someone should post this as an answer, for visibility

Comment: Thank you for those answers, I couldn't find it in the third edition of Royden, but it is in the fourth edition.